# Mongo db Array with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have an model :
         class Profile
         include Mongoid::Document

```
    # PROFILE TYPE KIDS & PARENT
    embeds_one :kids_type, :class_name => "ProfileKidsType"
    embeds_one :parent_type, :class_name => "ProfileParentType"

    end
```

and in ProfileKidsType model:

```
    class ProfileKidsType
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :nickname, :type => String
    field :gender, :type => String
```

....so on.....

```
    embedded_in :profile, :inverse_of => :kids_type
    end
```

in 
        views:profiles /_form.html.haml

```
    = form_for @profile do |f|

   .formBox
    .formSection Child information
    = f.label :lname, "Nick name"
    = f.text_field :nickname
```

how can i access nick name field here..... when i execute the above code it is saying undefined method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fields_for in order to create a nested form for an embedded doc.

Something like this would work:

```
  = form_for @profile do |f|

  .formBox
   .formSection Child information
   = f.fields_for :kids_type do |k|
     = k.label :nickname, "Nick name"
     = k.text_field :nickname
```

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663038/access-subcollection-in-mongoid-with-rails-form-to-edit-and-create-new-entry) for more detailed information, though it doesn't use haml.

Comment: You would use the same code, just put it in a partial like you did above: profiles /_form.html.haml and then render it from another (non-partial) view like profiles/edit.html.haml or profiles/new.html.haml